# Property animations and SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm creating an application that relies heavily on property animations for Android 3.0.  I have it working, but there are significant slowdowns in certain parts.  I believe that multi-threading the UI would help a lot.  Naturally, you can't really do that with Android's design.  What I was wondering was, is it possible to use render my `View` objects in a `SurfaceView` and use the property animation framework that's already in place?  I've seen examples on drawing objects using the `Canvas` class, but I don't want to re-implement all the animations when it's all right there.  I haven't seen anyone use any of the Andriod animation (frame, tween, property) in a SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android animations don't work in a SurfaceView, you have to do them manually with a secondary thread. It's not so hard, but you will need to rewrite almost everything.

If you use a lot of animations (like in a game) then you should really consider switching to a SurfaceView because it's way faster (and is the only way to get smooth animations in this case, since you probably hit the limit of these built-in animations, which have a lot of overhead). If you don't switch now, it will be even harder later...

I can provide you some samples if you decide to go this way.

Comment: I was just trying to avoid doing a lot of custom animation work as a lot of my framework is in place and it fits so nicely with the iOS version of this app.

Comment: But the android UI is slower than that of iOS, especially view animations. It improved a bit with android 4.0, but it is still behind. What kind of application do you develop? Do you really have a lot of animations?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  I was just seeing how much I could get away with.  The application that I'm developing requires a lot of bitmap translations.  I don't want to go into the details, but yes.  There are quite a few animations.  Using the View framework was the simplest way to use it and keep the same class structure that the rest of the team was using.  It worked pretty well with hardware acceleration enabled, but started slowing down as I added some.

Comment: I would suggest using the `traceview` tool, to see what functions slow down the app. Maybe you will be able to find a workaround. There may be also some technical issues but without any code, it is hard to help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to get a significant boost by removing views that were no longer visible which seemed to be the main cause of the slowdown.  Still would have liked some way of speeding up the UI rendering, but I guess I have to work with what I have.  Thanks again.